# Remove special Characters from a specific field

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have the below CSV file on unix, and I want to remove all the special characters and spaces from the last field only (separated by |), can you please help?

***current input:***

```
16-DEC-16 11:42:50 AM|VV161216.1142.H21611|01234567891|9876543210|155|BILLPAYMENT C.UTIL
```

***expected output:***

```
16-DEC-16 11:42:50 AM|VV161216.1142.H21611|01234567891|9876543210|155|BILLPAYMENTCUTIL
```

Comment: can the `|` delimiter be found (presumably escaped) in some fields?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and define what exactly means "all the special characters" you want to remove or define what characters should be kept in this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove all characters that are not upper case or lower case letters or digits (`[A-Za-z0-9]`) from the last field of every line you can use

```
awk -F '|' -v 'OFS=|' '{ gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/,"",$NF); print}' inputfile > outputfile
```

From the input line in the question this creates exactly the requested output line.

Comment: Stackoverflow says you can't upvote your own answer, but I could swear I just did !

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to remove non-alphanumeric characters, you can use the following `awk` command :

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } { gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "", $NF); print $0 }' inputFile
```

- `BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }` sets the field delimiter to `|` for output as well as input.
- `gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "", $NF)` replaces all sequences of non-alphanumeric characters in the last field by the empty string
- `print $0` outputs the updated row

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/XR4xVK).

Note that this relies on the absence of the `|` character in the fields' values, while CSV would allow use of its delimiter character escaped or inside quoted field values. If you're in such context, it would be best to use a pre-existing CSV parser.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/[^[:alnum:]|]([[:alnum:]]*)$/\1/;ta' file
```

This works backwards through each line removing any character other than `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or `_` until reaching the field delimiter `|` i.e. only operating on the last field of each line.

If the last field can only contain upper case alpha characters, use:

```
sed -E ':a;/s/[^A-Z|]([A-Z]*)$/\1/;ta' file
```